# errorMessage: "event is not defined" in lambda function nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to run a lambda function attached to an API gateway GET request and below is the code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const bucketName = "dhaval-upload";

let params = {
        Bucket: bucketName, 
        Key: event.fileName
};

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    return await s3.getObject(params).promise()
    .then((res) => {
        return "abcd";
        // return res.Body.toString('utf-8');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        return err;
    });
};
```

but I am getting the below error

```
errorMessage: "event is not defined"
errorType: "ReferenceError"
```

But I don't understand the reason for this as I have another POST request running perfectly..

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Look at the definition of `params`, event is not defined up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place params inside your handler, like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    let params = {
        Bucket: bucketName, 
        Key: event.fileName
    };

    return await s3.getObject(params).promise()
    .then((res) => {
        return "abcd";
        // return res.Body.toString('utf-8');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        return err;
    });
};
```